# Windows service endpoint naming and configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, config

I can't seem to figure out how to change the default endpoint for a C# Windows Service. Do you need to have some sort of path in there as well as the service name? Not getting any errors and the service runs, but I'm unable to navigate to the service. When I use the default path of the project it works fine.

Here's my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    <add key="baseAddress" value="http://192.168.1.23:8733/GPService/" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e34" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e34" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>

  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
    app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GPWebService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://TestServer:48620/Dynamics/GPService/GPService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GPWebService" contract="DynamicsGPService.DynamicsGP" name="GPWebService">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="user@testdomain.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

    <services>
      <service name="WcfGPServiceLibrary.GPService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.23:8733/GPService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  contract="WcfGPServiceLibrary.IGPService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="192.168.1.23" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
            set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
            set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
            to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough for me. The URI to your service is:
' http ://192.168.1.23:8733/GPService/'. What do you mean by default endpoint?

Comment: @Legart Basically when you just generate the project so you've got something like this: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WindowsService1/WindowsService1

Comment: Ok, I see, it's auto generated code. And the service works with auto-generated endpoint address, but doesn't work with once you set to it. Am I right?

Comment: @Legart Exactly! And I'm just not sure what I need to be referencing or what kind of path I should be putting in there.

Comment: If you are hosting it as a console application or windows service, it really doesn't matter the path you have chosen. In case you host it on IIS, the path must be the same as path to your application on IIS (you can click on your scv file brow, it will show the expected path). I whould say, that the base address should be "http ://192.168.1.23:8733/" (without space) and endpoint address "GPService". For the client it should be available on address - "http ://192.168.1.23:8733/GPService" (under client / endpoint / address)

Comment: It looks like you have a WCF service **library** - you need to copy the relevant `<system.serviceModel>` section to your Windows service app config file.  Libraries use the configuration file of the consuming/hosting application, not their own config file.  Also, can you post the code from your Windows service where you are hosting the service?